# Using Chai - how to check object property contains DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, tdd, bdd, chai

How can I test that an object property contains the value of a DOM element in Chai, eg:

```
someObject = function(){
    element: $('#foo');
}
```

How do I check that element equals the jquery object $('#foo')?

So far, I have tried:

```
someObject.should.have.property('element', $('#foo')
someObject.should.have.property('element').with.value($('#foo'))
```

But these fail.

Anyone have any ideas? ( Setup - Requirejs, Mocha, Chai )

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `$()`, you get back a **new** object wrapping the matched elements (if any). To access the actual DOM element in your example, you need to use `[0]` (since in your example, there will be only one matched element or none).

Something along the lines of:

```
someObject.should.have.deep.property('element[0]', $('#foo')[0])
```